# Print menu and sub menu in angular8 from json data

Tags: json, angular

i want to print menu and sub menu from below json ie.

About Us --> about 2.1

```
           about 2.2
```

Contact Us --> contact 1

```
           contact 2

           cont
```

feedback --> feed 1 --> feed 2

print menu and sub menu from json data
        '{
    "menuBean": {
        "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
        "label": "Top Menu",
        "parentObjectIdHex": null,
        "path": [
            {
                "objectIdHex": null,
                "label": "root"
            }
        ],
        "subMenu": [
            {
                "objectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
                "label": "About Us"
            },
            {
                "objectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
                "label": "Contact Us"
            },
            {
                "objectIdHex": "5e7c2eafa758800e908d8bc4",
                "label": "feedback"
            }
        ],
        "level": 1,
        "textContent": "",
        "contents": []
    },
    "subMenuList": [
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
            "label": "About Us",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c4bc2a758800e908d8bd3",
                    "label": "about 2.1"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c4c21a758800e908d8bd4",
                    "label": "about 2.2"
                }
            ],
            "level": 2
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c4bc2a758800e908d8bd3",
            "label": "about 2.1",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
                    "label": "About Us"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c4c21a758800e908d8bd4",
            "label": "about 2.2",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7b2159a758800e908d8bc1",
                    "label": "About Us"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
            "label": "Contact Us",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c3bd5a758800e908d8bd0",
                    "label": "contact 1"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c4b71a758800e908d8bd1",
                    "label": "contact2"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c4b8ca758800e908d8bd2",
                    "label": "cont"
                }
            ],
            "level": 2
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c3bd5a758800e908d8bd0",
            "label": "contact 1",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
                    "label": "Contact Us"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c4b71a758800e908d8bd1",
            "label": "contact2",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
                    "label": "Contact Us"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c4b8ca758800e908d8bd2",
            "label": "cont",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7b21dda758800e908d8bc2",
                    "label": "Contact Us"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c2eafa758800e908d8bc4",
            "label": "feedback",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c2f8aa758800e908d8bc5",
                    "label": "feed 1"
                }
            ],
            "level": 2
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c2f8aa758800e908d8bc5",
            "label": "feed 1",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7c2eafa758800e908d8bc4",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c2eafa758800e908d8bc4",
                    "label": "feedback"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c32eba758800e908d8bc6",
                    "label": "feed 2"
                }
            ],
            "level": 3
        },
        {
            "objectIdHex": "5e7c32eba758800e908d8bc6",
            "label": "feed 2",
            "parentObjectIdHex": "5e7c2f8aa758800e908d8bc5",
            "path": [
                {
                    "objectIdHex": null,
                    "label": "root"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e78a85fa758801914c3df8f",
                    "label": "Top Menu"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c2eafa758800e908d8bc4",
                    "label": "feedback"
                },
                {
                    "objectIdHex": "5e7c2f8aa758800e908d8bc5",
                    "label": "feed 1"
                }
            ],
            "subMenu": [],
            "level": 4
        }
    ]
}'

Comment: It will be better to understand if you will provide the question with an example :)

Comment: About Us --> about 2.1

                     about 2.2

Answer (score -1):

```
 <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.activeli]="menu.active" class="nav-item">

                    <!-- child menu had  -->
                    <a class="menu nav-link">
                        <p>{{ menu.label }}</p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="submenu" #submenu [style.height.px]="menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight : 0"
                        *ngIf="menu.subMenu>
                        <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.subMenu">
                            <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                                <p>{{ submenu.label }}</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sorry it does not work for me.

Comment: Please do not answer questions like this where the OP has made zero effort. It just makes them go on to ask [even more low-effort questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383035/protect-existing-pdf-file-in-folder-with-password-and-email-as-attachment-in-asp) and degrades the quality of the site as a whole.